# Packing spheres in a sphere

Tags: packing-problem

For dimension $d$, let $N(r,d)$ = number of spheres of radius $r$ which can be packed in a sphere of radius 1.

For dimension 1, $N(r,1) = \lfloor 1/r \rfloor$.

From the articles below, I infer that $N$ does not have a closed form for higher dimensions.

- [Circle packing in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)
- [Sphere packing in a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere)

I would like to know more and am looking for a good starting point.
Any ideas?
Thanks.
--Len

Comment: What articles are you referring to? I believe you may have forgotten to include a link.